# How do I import python table data into an sql table?

Tags: python, dataframe

```
import mysql.connector

mydb = mysql.connector.connect(
    host="localhost",
    user="root",
    passwd="password",
    database="stocksdatabase"
    )
mycursor = mydb.cursor()

import yfinance as yf
ticker = yf.Ticker("MSFT")
hist=ticker.history(period="max")

column_str = """id, Date, Open, High, 
          Low, Close, Volume, Dividends, Stock Splits"""
insert_str = ("%s, " * 9)[:-2]
final_str = "INSERT INTO historical_price (%s) VALUES (%s)" % (column_str, insert_str)

mycursor.execute(final_str, hist)
mydb.commit()
```

I get the error "The truth value of a DataFrame is ambiguous. Use a.empty, a.bool(), a.item(), a.any() or a.all()."

How can I approach this?

Answer (score 0):

You are trying to insert an entire dataframe into a table. The parameters keyword of `execute` can only accept [a tuple or a dictonary](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/connector-python/en/connector-python-api-mysqlcursor-execute.html). You probably need to iterate over the entire dataframe and enter the data per row. Something along the lines of (not tested):

```py
for index, row in hist.iterrows():
    mycursor.execute(final_str, row)
mydb.commit()
```

Comment: `iterrows` should be changed into `iterrows()`.

Comment: My bad. Fixed...

Comment: it doesn't work

Comment: I'd like to help, but what do you get as errormessages?